# Which protocols can be used to automatically set up inbound port-forwarding?

Tags: network-programming, server, port, router

Today many of the routers do not forward inbound traffic from internet to LAN devices by default.

What are the best standards to use for my application to set up a dynamic inbound port-forwarding automatically for my services (UDP and/or TCP)?

I'm looking for solution like UPnP or whatever. It'd also need to be backwards compatible with old routers/modem.

P.S. How do software like utorrend implement this?

Comment: the STUN protocol: see references here http://www.stunprotocol.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some solutions I found:

- Internet Gateway Device Standardized Device Control Protocol (IGD), by uPnp.
- Application-level gateway (ALG).
- STUN (thanks Sigismondo).
- NAT Port Mapping Protocol (PMP) for MAC devices.

Others ? Pro and cons ? compatibility ?

Answer (score 0):

You need portforwarding. You need to know the ip adres of your server. For windows i use ipconfig, but you did not mention your OS.
Then you need to access your router (via your browser, type in the ipadres of your router itself). There you can login into your router and access the menu of the router. Search for portforwarding and set redirect the port you want to your server. I suppose you use your server as a bittorrent client:)

Comment: No, sorry, i mean that the sofware automatically, forward the server, not the user. I updated the question, thanks.

Comment: At least you have to login into your router, and try to find an option like:  Remote Management. This will be off by default. Somewhere it shouldbe possible to set allowid ip (range). This is a very general desciption. Now  search for your routers info if it is possible to use a kind of script which can do the jo for you. But.....assuming you want a uTorrent server: (you did not deny it), usually all this is not needed....every torrentclient should ususally work behind a router. (mine does, as wellwith a laptop as an raspberry, both without the need to change settings in my router.)